# Apache no funciona en Xampp

Tags: apache, windows-server

Hola resulta que en donde estoy haciendo practicas quieres hacer inventarios de los equipos que tiene la empresa y me dijeron que antes usaban el OCS Inventory usa una interfaz web y un cliente o agente para mandar los datos al servidor, habia logrado hacer que funcionara en mi laptop con Windows 10 y me dicen que lo menta al servidor que es un windows server 2008 había logrado que mostrara la interfaz pero no que recibiera los datos usaba el puerto 8083 de apache cambien unos archivos de la carpeta perls y ya no funciono y me sale los siguientes errores no puedo finalizar el proceso que tiene ocupado el puerto 80 ni el 443 ya estan ocupados por otros programas que usan en la empresa había visto en otros tutoriales que había problemas con perl cambien unos archivos y desde entonces a no trabajo bien. 
Ya no se que hacer y vengo pedirles ayuda Gracias!

```
[![introducir el código aquí][1]][1]
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: debes cambiarlo en configuracion->servicios y puertos->apache->sslport

Comment: ok gracias crees que no sea por cambiar los archivos de la carpeta perl?